# configuring HTTPS enabled WCF with SSL that has a CN of *.domain.com

Tags: wcf, iis, ssl, https, web-config

I'm trying to configure a SSL enabled WCF web service thats deployed in IIS 6.

The CN of the SSL is ***.domain.com** and setting it up in the web.config throws an exception that it cannot locate a CN of this.

```
<serverCertificate findValue="CN = *.domain.com"/>
```

Any idea how to fix this?